# Why does the printf family of functions care about locale?

Tags: c++, ios, c, unicode, localization

In iOS, if I use `vswprintf` with a non-western locale, it will fail and return -1.

However, if I set the locale correctly it will write properly.

Why is this? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the reference that says `vswprintf` will return `-1` when used with a non-western locale?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085751/swprintf-chokes-on-characters-outside-8-bit-range

Comment: I don't understand your question. `vswprintf` cares about the locale because depending on the users native language, country, etc. you don't always want to use the default locale.

Comment: I thought vswprintf will print to stdout and does not care what the bytes carry. No?

Comment: @mskw: If that were true, the output would be unreadable nonsense in the most common cases. (Try using a `putchar` loop instead of `vswprintf` for a static string and watch the nonsense you get if you don't care what the bytes carry.)

Comment: @mskw: `vswprintf` and family *formats* the output. It has to know how to interpret the bytes. For example, I can make it output `Monday 07/30/12 09:42:22` with the default locale or `月曜日 2012/07/30 9:42:59` if I set the locale to Japanese on my system with the same string.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now!  And the person below, also had the exact issue I was having. I hope I don't have to implement that on iOS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strangely, the implementation of `vswprintf` on iOS converts the wide string arguments it's given to narrow strings and then converts the result back to a wide string (I had to debug this issue once).  If your wide strings contain non-ASCII characters in them, then this is a lossy conversion, and only certain characters can be successfully converted.

The exact set of non-ASCII characters which can be converted depends on the current locale setting.  If you try to pass in unsupported characters, then `vswprintf` will fail by returning `-1` and setting `errno` to the error `EILSEQ` (illegal multibyte sequence).

On Mac OS X, at least, you can get around this by switching to a UTF-8 locale, e.g.:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8")
```

However, this doesn't appear to work on iOS, so if you need to be able to `vswprintf` all characters without knowing the locale in advance, I'm afraid you're out of luck unless you reimplement `vswprintf` yourself.